# Using HTML tags in Transact SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I Saw the below code in one of our application's stored procedures.

```
     SELECT 
        '<tr style=''color: blue; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; ''><td>' +    
        '</td><td align=center>' + 
        CASE WHEN sunfrom = '00:00 AM' OR sunto = '00:00 AM' THEN 'CLOSED' else
        isnull(left(convert(char(8),sunfrom, 108),5),'') + '-' + isnull(left(convert(char(8),sunto, 108),5),'')  END +
        '</td><td align=center>' + 
        CASE WHEN monfrom = '00:00 AM' OR monto = '00:00 AM' THEN 'CLOSED' else
        isnull(left(convert(char(8),monfrom, 108),5),'') + '-' + isnull(left(convert(char(8),monto, 108),5),'')  END
        FROM dates
```

It seems like HTML tags are used. I need to know the purpose of this query. can any one help?

Comment: someone has made a very nice architectural decision to implement the web design using t-sql , and that was not ironic....

Comment: yes. the design seems terrible. But, I am amazed to know that we can do web design using t-sql even though it is not a advisable :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it builds a html string , concatenating with some column data , looks like it produces table rows

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is generating an "opening hours" table for a website. Something like:

```
Sun      Mon             Tue             Wed
CLOSED   9:00AM-5:00PM   9:30AM-5:30PM   CLOSED
```

The generated HTML string would look like (with formatting):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Sun</td>
    <td>Mon</td>
    <td>Tue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='color: blue; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; '>
    <td></td>
    <td align=center>CLOSED</td>
    <td align=center>9:00AM-5:00PM</td>
    <td align=center>9:30AM-5:30PM</td>
    <td align=center>CLOSED</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: By the way, I definitely agree with @Thorarins that it is a terrible design decision to be assembling this HTML string using T-SQL...

Comment: the stored procedure take much time to execute with little amount of data. definitely a performance hindering approach

Comment: Yeah, not too nice! A big issue is that it also makes the T-SQL code really hard to read - would be nice to have some separation between the SQL & HTML.